# How to boot ubuntu installation from usb in bios?

Tags: system-installation

What to choose if i want to install ubuntu from bootable pendrive with ubuntu iso installation?[image]

Comment: Is there another OS on the target HDD? Is it BIOS or UEFI? How did you make the USB?

Comment: In my Dell Precision M4800, I can select LEGACY BOOT: USB Storage (for BIOS mode) **or** UEFI BOOT: UEFI: <name of device> (for UEFI mode). This works with USB drives ***cloned*** from the iso file. Maybe your USB drive does not boot in both boot modes, maybe it does not boot at all. Please describe what happens, when you select one of the options, maybe it boots, but there are problems with the graphics. If problems with graphics, please try the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're booting from BIOS, select USB device. Place it first in the boot order if you need to. Legacy Boot from USB or use Sandisk Partition 1.